# OnMouseOver com Delay ao trocar imagem

Tags: javascript

Estou usando um `onmouseover`, porém está dando `delay` de 0.5 a 1 segundo para trocar a imagem, quando coloco na minha hospedagem.

```
 <li>
    <img src="images/clientes/1.png"onmouseover="this.src='images/clientes/a1.png'"onmouseout="this.src='images/clientes/1.png'"/>
</li>
```

Comment: Isso depende do carregamento da imagem. Pode ser que o servidor está um pouco mais lento do que sua aplicação no local.

Comment: tem um jeito de consertar?

Comment: o maximo que cada imagem vai é 30 KB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como as duas imagens estão hospedadas em um host remoto, é natural ter que esperar o tempo de carregamento da mesma.

Neste caso, você pode realizar um pré-carregamento das imagens, uma das formas de se fazer isso é com JavaScript.:

```
//liste no Array abaixo todas as imagens que deseja realizar o pré-carregamento.
var imagemURLs = [
  "images/clientes/1.png",
  "images/clientes/a1.png"
];

imagemURLs.forEach(function (imagemURL, indice) {
  new Image().src = imagemURL;
});
```

Comment: vlw irmão, funcionou.

Comment: só que vc colocou trocou o n pelo M em um dos imagemURLs